# Polymer 1.0: Referencing a path for an imported style sheet using a custom-style

Tags: html, css, polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

[I'm trying to understand this example](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/todo-list/blob/master/app/elements/todo-view/todo-view.html).

Code

```
<link rel="import" href="../../styles/app-theme.html"> <!--Line 22-->
...
<style is="custom-style" include="app-theme"></style> <!--Line 32-->
```

### Question

In line 32, does the `app-theme` value for the `include` attribute refer to the `app-theme.html` import in line 22? If so, how does the compiler discover the path of the `app-theme.html` import if it's not included somewhere in the `<style>` tag's set of attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really just references the id of the `dom-module` with the style you want to use.

```
<dom-module id="app-theme">
  <template>
    <style>
     .red { color: red; }
    </style> 
  </template>
</dom-module>
```